# Mass Regex Replace

Tags: html, css, regex

I'm trying to tweak a style sheet a friend gave to me. It's rather long and all of the special css attributes, rather than being defined with -webkit or -moz, are defined with -ms, for Microsoft. Is there a way with regex to replace

```
-ms-something: somethingelse;
```

with

```
-ms-something: somethingelse;
-moz-something: somethingelse;
-webkit-something: somethingelse;
-o-something: somethingelse;
```

in a big mass replace?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What tool/language do you use for regex?

Comment: The replace in Sublime Text lets me use regex.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
search: -ms-([^;]+;)
replace: $0\r\n-o-$1\r\n-moz-$1\r\n-webkit-$1\r\n
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this for BBEdit, but it should work for any text editor with grep replace.

**Search**

```
^-ms-(.*):(.*);$
```

**Replace**

```
-ms-\1:\2;
-moz-\1:\2;
-webkit-\1:\2;
-o-\1:\2;
```

**Example**

*Before-Replace*

```
-ms-property: value;
```

*After-Replace*

```
-ms-property: value;
-moz-property: value;
-webkit-property: value;
-o-property: value;
```